# Enqueue... methods not recognised while unit testing asynchronous methods in WP7

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-7, asynchronous

I've just started working on testing WP7 apps and I have a problem with testing asynchronous methods in WP7.

Following post at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/158531/The-Unit-Test-of-Silverlight-Applications-with-Asy
I written test class and implemented test method:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [Asynchronous]
    public void AsynchronousWCFCallWithGetStudentWCFCommand()
    {
        MainPageViewModel vm = new MainPageViewModel();
        bool done = false;
        vm.AsyncCallbackCompleted += (() => done = true);

        EnqueueCallback(() => vm.GetStudentWCFCommand.Execute(null));
        EnqueueConditional(() => done);
        EnqueueCallback(() => Assert.IsNotNull(vm.StudentList,
            "No student retrieved from the WCF service"));
        EnqueueCallback(() => Assert.IsTrue(vm.StudentList.Count == 10,
            "The number of the students should be 10."));

        EnqueueTestComplete();
    }
```

However, when I build the project, VS2010 doesn't recognise any of Enqueue methods giving me errors like: "The name 'EnqueueTestComplete' does not exist in the current context"

I added binaries from Jeff Wilcox website: http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/05/sl3-utf-bits/ to my testing project. And in the test class I've got these 2 using statements:

```
    using Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
```

What am I missing? Can you put any light on my problem?

Comment: Don't suppose you forgot to inherit the SilverlightTest class?

Comment: I knew I missed something obvious but I didn't think I had such a bad day. Thanks for pointing this out. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing a Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango) app? If so, then you are using the wrong assemblies, you want the updated ones found here [jeff.wilcox/2011/06/updated-ut-mango-bits](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/06/updated-ut-mango-bits/). After replacing the assemblies in your project you'll need to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Sorry I've forgotten to add in the post. I'm developing for Windows Phone 7.0.